# Using MySQL, PHP and cron to sum daily values based on timestamped data

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I am trying to piece together a bunch of steps and it is getting confusing.

I have a MySQL table with (MySQL) timestamp and runtime fields. I would like to make another table containing date and sum (runtime) fields.

I would like to execute a cron job every day after midnight to sum the runtimes from the day before and insert that with the date of the previous day.

I would like the cron job to make sure that the prior days were run, and if not, it would run those as well.

I am new to cron, so I don't know if that last step is necessary.

Here are my trouble points:

1. Writing a query that will convert timestamps to dates and sum each date.
2. Setting up a PHP cron job that will make sure all dates are entered but not double enter.

Here's the code I've tried on part 1 (I'm running on CURDATE until it works):

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT SUM(runtime) AS value_today FROM `table` WHERE date = CURDATE()",$link)
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row[value_today];
```

Comment: Did you tried anything yet ? Do you have any code to share ?

Comment: @Nirnae I just added some of the code. I found the 'AS value_today' from another post but am not sure how to properly use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of convert timestamp from query, why dont just set a variable using php by

```
$yesterday_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 days'))
```

to get yesterday date

then query

```
SELECT SUM(runtime) AS total FROM db_table WHERE DATE(date_run) = '" . $yesterday_date . "' GROUP BY DATE(date_run)"
```

Comment: I'll give this a try. Newb question: How do I use "AS total" in php? Convert to a $var?

Comment: when you declare the column as total. and your mysql_fetch_array($result) will return this

Array{
  [total]  => value of total
}

so you may just echo out by echo $row['total']

Comment: Please mark it as answer if it helped :) so people will take it when researching.

Comment: The only thing remaining is how code the cron job to verify that it only adds data once.

Comment: Just create a function that contain your this code and setup cron job at your server side to automatically call this function daily..  Your data once i assume is each date got insert only once by the function..  So which means that everytime you run your function at 12.00am.. It will only take the value of yesterday and ignore other date..  Data will enter based on how many times you call the function.  Else you may create another query to check if the date already occur in your database you may just update it instead of insert it. You using cpanel or other?

Comment: The update should work. I was thinking up updating the past 5 days or so in case it doesn't run for some reason. I am using cpanel.

Comment: if you are using cpanel, you may just look for a cron job button and set up your cron job over there by calling the url that link to your function.